# Clicking relative link goes to about:<relative link> which does not show wanted page

Tags: delphi

I am using version 14.67.9 of TembeddedWB in a project in delphi 2007. I use TembeddedWB in combination with loadfromstring. That all works like I want it to but when clicking on a link in the page it goes to a page I am not expecting. If for instance the page is on a particular IMDB result site and one clicks on the link  the browser goes to about:/title/tt1041829/. I guess I forgot to set some extra property or I am doing something else wrong. If somebody here can point me in the right way i would appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the web page you are accessing uses relative links and the reference point that it would be relative too is your loadfromstring which loads through the "about:blank" page.  Another way of fixing this would be to inject a <BASE href="http://www.originaldomain.com/originalpath"> tag in the HTML header (between the <HEAD> and </HEAD> tags) which points to the location the page was accessed from.  This will tell the browser where relative tags start from and will fix the problem without requiring inspection of every link.

Comment: How do you "inject" the BASE tag in the HTML header?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the browser's current URL is not updated and the default "about:blank" is used. I guess this may happen when you don't navigate to the web site directly by `Navigate` or `Navigate2` method but load the HTML from a local file or stream.

Edit: I see, you are using LoadFromString which confirms that.

In that case, it should be possible to use `OnBeforeNavigate2` event to fix the URL.