# How to insert a tag at specific position into TEmbeddedWB document?

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe2, tembeddedwb

In a web-page document loaded in TEmbeddedWB, I need to insert a `BASE` tag (pointing to the source URL of the document) at the beginning of the `HEAD` section (right after the `<HEAD>` tag).
Example: `<head><base href="http://adomain.com/mypage.html">`.
What is the best procedure to achieve this?

Comment: As an alternative, you could consider [handling the `OnBeforeNavigate2` event to adjust the clicked-on URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1038478/33732).

Comment: @RobKennedy Rob, the program does not know the source URL, because it loads the document with `TEmbeddedWB.LoadFRomFile` from a local file. So I DO have to save and associate the source URL somehow to the saved document. And the most logical way to do this would be to insert the BASE tag.